# How to make a stab function?

Tags: unity, c#, javascript

I've looked around everywhere, and I can't find an example script for a stab. What I have so far is a top down 2D scene, with a player at the bottom (static). I would like to have the sword/tongue to translate/moveTo upwards to a maxTranslation, then back to the player. While the the "sword" is still in motion, I would like to lock the Input key, so that the player cannot hit the button again while the sword is already out.

So far, this is what I have tried:

```
#pragma strict

var cancelMove : boolean;
var speed : int;
var maxTranslation : double;

function Start () {
    transform.position.z = -0.5;
    speed = 20; // Input speed here
    maxTranslation = 11.8; // Input max translation here
}

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")) {
        moveTo(maxTranslation, speed);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp ("space") && !cancelMove) {
        cancelMove = true;
        moveTo(-11, speed);
    }
}

function moveTo (posY : float, speed : float)
{
    if (posY != -11) {
        while (transform.position.y != posY && Input.GetKey ("space") && !cancelMove)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards (transform.position, new Vector2(transform.position.x, posY), speed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield;
        }
    }
    else {
        while (transform.position.y != -11) {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards (transform.position, new Vector2(transform.position.x, posY), speed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield;
        }
        cancelMove = false;
    }
}
```

And:

```
#pragma strict

function Start () {
    transform.position.z = -0.5;
}

function Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown ("space"))
    {
        moveTo(transform.position.y + 10, 50); // Feed the moveTo() function the X/Y positions you want to move it to, and the Speed you want to move at
    }
    transform.position.z = -0.5;
}

function moveTo(posY : float, speed : float)
{
    while (transform.position.y != posY)
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards (transform.position, new Vector2(transform.position.x, posY), speed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield;
    }
}
```

So in the end, how would I implement:

1. A "whip-like" function, where the tongue/sword translates upwards, stays for an interval of about 0.5 seconds, and returns to its original position.
2. The player hitting "space" while the tongue is already out will not do anything.

Comment: What is a *stab function*? Do you mean an *animation*? What's this about a *tongue*?

Comment: Taken out of context @Anko, that sounds worrying... :P

Answer (score -2):

It would be better to animate sword rather than make it move through code.